# Vertically centering an image at the end of a sentence (h2)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to add an image at the end of a heading (H2 tag). The icon is smaller than the height of the text and therefore, for things to look good, I'd like the **image** to be vertically centered with regards to the text.

I tried different approach can't but can't make it work.

- I tried to nest `img` in a `div` that's nested in the `h2` declaration. Make the `div` a `inline-flex` element and make the items contained in this `div` vertically centered. This **only** works if the `div` contains some text (`<h2>blab bla<div class="wrapper">XX<img.../></div></h2>`). Otherwise it seems that it doesn't know its height and therefore the contained `img` is not aligned.
- I tried to make it work without a wrapper. Just declaring the `img` after the text contained within the `<h2></h2>` tag. Without much success.

I tried all sort of combinations, forcing the height of the `<div>` wrapper, etc. Just can't make it work. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9o7argy/1/#&togetherjs=gUSdwn2Axc)

In summary, I'd like to achieve the first result but without the xx inside the `div`.)

[image]

EDIT

With an image added (32x32). I added it to the jsfiddle.

[image]

```
<style>
.content
{
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.content h2
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    line-height: 2.85em;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.wrapper
{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.end-of-line
{
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}

.h2-test
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.h2-test > img
{
    border: 1px solid violet;
}
</style>

<div class="content">

<h2>this is a test and it goes on multiple lines otherwise it would be a bit too simple. Of course, I like HTML and CSS but I find that sometimes it's horribly difficult to make simple things work. Hopefully I can count on people on Stackverflow.<div class="wrapper">XX<img class="end-of-line" src=""/></div></h2>

<h2 class="h2-test">this is a test and it goes on multiple lines otherwise it would be a bit too simple. Of course, I like HTML and CSS but I find that sometimes it's horribly difficult to make simple things work. Hopefully I can count on people on Stackverflow.<img class="end-of-line" src=""/></h2>

<p>Some content after that.</p>
```

Comment: What about adding `display: flex` to your `.end-of-line`?

Comment: @ChenBr It would to be `inline-flex` otherwise the image goes on the next line? This puts the image after the last character in the sentence, but the image is not vertically aligned.

Comment: Mind adding images to your fiddle so I will understand you better?

Comment: @ChenBr: Just did it) Thank you. Also made an edit above to show what the expected result is with the image in. Of course I am still using the xx trick.

Comment: Try to add `vertical-align: text-bottom;` to your image's class. Also, remove the wrapper.

Comment: @ChenBr yes this would work. Happy to accept this as an answer if you make one) Thank you. I have added the solution in the meantime (above).

Comment: Happy I could help, added an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

Instead of wrapping the image with a container and applying too many flex classes, skip the wrapper (remove it) and use the class `vertical-align: text-bottom;` to your image.

You can align your image in a surprising amount of ways:

```
/* Keyword values */
vertical-align: baseline;
vertical-align: sub;
vertical-align: super;
vertical-align: text-top;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
vertical-align: middle;
vertical-align: top;
vertical-align: bottom;

/* <length> values */
vertical-align: 10em;
vertical-align: 4px;

/* <percentage> values */
vertical-align: 20%;

/* Global values */
vertical-align: inherit;
vertical-align: initial;
vertical-align: revert;
vertical-align: revert-layer;
vertical-align: unset;
```

[line-height docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Working fiddle with your original code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ChenBr/6bc0wrgq/1/).

Answer (score -3):

you could try something like that maybe:

try removing the styling on the `h2` tag

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <h2>........</h2>
    <img class='image'>.......</img>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a valid CSS syntax, the values shouldn't be wrapped in apostrophes

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work if the content of the h2 tag is on multiple lines. This is the reason why I have made it a long string in my example. If the text fits on a line,  the 2 elements are obviously aligned. But on multiple line, the image needs to be right after the last character of the string contained in the h2 tag. Makes sense?